# Probability of defective product

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I've tried using Bayes Theorem and Tree diagram for this problem. I seem to be missing something. Can someone help?

Q:The market is equipped with the same product by three factories. 50% of the market is supplied by
the first factory, 30% - by the second factory. The average percentage of deficiencies in the
production of the first factory is 3%, of the second is 4% and the third - 5%. The bought element
appeared to be defective. Calculate the probability that it comes from the second factory. From
which factory is it most likely to buy the product?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried using Bayes Theorem?

Comment: This is how i interpreted it. I am not sure if i'm right. P(defective|First Factory ) = P(First Factory |Defective) * P(Defective) / P(First Factory)                                                  P(First Factory |Defective)  = 0.03      P(First Factory)=0.50   but i don't know how to find P(Defective)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 1,000 products. The total number of defectives are 37 so divided:

- 15 from Factory 1 ; ($1000\times50\%\times 3\%\ $)
- 12 from Factory 2 ; ($1000\times 30\%\times 4\%\ $)
- 10 from Factory 3 ; ($1000\times 20\%\times 5\%\ $)

Thus, given a defective (37 choices), the probability that it comes from Factory 1 is simply

$\frac{15}{37}$

from the second Factory  $\frac{12}{37}$ and from the third  Factory  $\frac{10}{37}$

Comment: That was a perfect explanation. Thank you so so much. I really appreciate your help.